# How do i convert a SymPy expression into polynomials?

Tags: julia, sympy, pycall

I want to change a SymPy expression, for example `x+y` ( `x=symbols("x")` and the same thing for `y`), into a polynomial, and then get the generators of this polynomial and the length of this polynomial.

I've tried

```
op=x+y
op = op[:as_poly](domain="C")
op_a = op.x[:gens]
nab = op[:length]()
```

but it seems that it doesn't work .

The error that i'm getting is this:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Sym, ::Symbol)
Closest candidates are:
  getindex(::Sym, ::Sym...) at /Users/midow/.julia/packages/SymPy/1Cwgd/src/utils.jl:18
  getindex(::Number) at number.jl:75
  getindex(::Number, ::Integer) at number.jl:77
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[11]:1
```

Comment: Hi @Marouane1994! I fixed your code formatting a bit, and tried to improve some parts of the text. Please make sure I didn't change any relevant parts of the meaning.

Comment: I never used `PyCall`, but we recently got `getproperty` overloading in Julia. Maybe the `getindex` interface is is deprecated? Have you tried something like `op.as_poly(domain = "C")`?

Answer (score 1):

As @phipsgabler mentioned, the interface changed from `getindex` to `getproperty` so

```
using SymPy
x=symbols("x")
y=symbols("y")
op = op.as_poly(domain="C")
op_a = op.x.gens
nab = op.length()
```

should give you what you want.